# CUSTOM RELATIVE between two securities

Tags: pine-script

there is a Study to build a RELATIVE between two symbols that is like this:

`

```
study("RELATIVE STRENGTH", shorttitle="RS") 
a = tickerid 
b = input("SPY", type=symbol) 
as = security(a, period, close) 
bs = security(b, period, close) 
plot(as/bs, title="RS", color=blue)
```

`

This works fine to do relatives with SPY. But I would like to make the divisor customizable in Pine. for example, depending on the sector of the active security, I would like to choose in PINE the appropriate sector ETF(I have tried using if...else). I am new to programming in PINE, and I cannot make it . I have looked for a simmilar formula but I do not find it. This is what I have done and it says: "Mismatched input 'b' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

```
`

//@version=2

study("RELATIVE STRENGTH", shorttitle="RS") 
a = ticker    // or tickerid ???
//b = input("SPX500USD", type=symbol) 

if a == "AAPL"  
     b := input("XLK", type=symbol) 
     
    else if a == "AMZN"
        b := input("XLY", type=symbol) 
    
    else
        b := input("SPY", type=symbol) 

as = security(a, period, close) 
bs = security(b, period, close) 
plot(as/bs, title="RS", color=blue)
```

`

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve it . Just add this lines to the @e2e4 code

```
myLabel = label.new(bar_index[0],secA/secB ,"/"+str.tostring(b), color = color.white, style = label.style_label_left, textcolor = color.blue, size=size.normal )

label.delete(myLabel[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `inputs` in Pine Script could not change during the runtime and should be known at the compilation stage. Moreover, the `request.security()` function accepts only a simple form of strings for the `symbol=` argument, hence the mutable **b** variable in your example is not compatible with the security functions.

Instead of input, that could not be changed from the Pine script during the runtime, you can use the ternary `?:` operator and hardcore the values for **b** to make it compatible with the security calls. The script below uses the Pine Script version 5 compiler directive:

```
//@version=5

indicator("RELATIVE STRENGTH", shorttitle="RS") 
ticker = syminfo.ticker
var string b = ticker == "AAPL" ? "XLK" : ticker == "AMZN" ? "XLY" : "SPY"

secA = request.security(ticker, timeframe.period, close) 
secB = request.security(b, timeframe.period, close) 
plot(secA/secB, title="RS", color=color.blue)
```

Comment: e2e4  thank you very much for your great solution

I have one last issue regarding this indicator. I would like to see the symbol of secB in the indicator, either on the indcator title or in the chart itself. I have used one of your recent posts to other user to get the idea of using "label.new", but even though I get the label in the chart, the indicator turns to be a ZERO LINE. This is what I have added to your solution

```
mylabel = label.new(bar_index,low, str.tostring(b), color = color.lime, style = label.style_label_up)
label.delete(mylabel[1])
```
Regards

Comment: Sorry, missed the comment, the comment section is not the right place to ask new questions, create a new one. Anyway, if you are going to update the label on every single bar, it's not efficient to create and delete the label on every bar. Initialize the single label and use the label.set_* commands to update it.

Comment: could you please share with me how you would Initialize the single label and use the label.set_* commands to update it please, I do not know how to do it

`myLabel = label.new(bar_index[0],secA/secB ,"/"+str.tostring(b), color = color.white, style = label.style_label_left, textcolor = color.blue, size=size.normal )

label.delete(myLabel[1])`